# How to extract n-th occurence of a pattern with regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Let's say I have a string like this:

`my_string = "my string a-maxeka UU-AA-19.01.03-20.01.22-bamdanool"`

And I'd like to extract the first and the second date separately with `stringr`.

I tried something like `str_extract(my_string, '(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+){n}')` and while it works when `n=1` it doesn't work with `n=2`. How can I extract the second occurence?

Example of `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(string_col = c("my string a-maxeka UU-AA-19.01.03-20.01.22-bamdanool", 
                                "my string a-maxeka UU-AA-20.01.08-20.04.01-jdasdasd", 
                                "asdad asda-adsad KK-ASD-20.05.05-jjj"))
```

And I want to create columns `date1`, `date2`.

#### Edit:

Although @RonanShah and @ThomasIsCoding provided solutions based on `str_extract_all`, I'd really like to get to know how we can do it using regex only as finding n-th occurence seems to be important pattern and potentially may result in much neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

(I) Capturing groups (marked by `()`) can be multiplied by `{n}` but will then count only as one capture group and match the last instance. If you explicitly write down capturing gorups for both dates, you *can* use `str_match` (without the "`_all`"):

```r
> stringr::str_match(df$string_col, '(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)-(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)?')[, -1, drop = FALSE]
     [,1]       [,2]      
[1,] "19.01.03" "20.01.22"
[2,] "20.01.08" "20.04.01"
[3,] "20.05.05" NA
```

Here, `?` makes the occurrence of the second date optional and `[, -1, drop = FALSE]` removes the first column that always contains the whole match. You might want to change the `-` in the pattern to something more general.

To really find only the `n`th match, you could use (I) in a expression like this:

```r
stringr::str_match(df$string_col, paste0('(?:(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*){', n, '}'))[, -1]
[1] "0.01.22" "0.04.01" NA
```

Here, we used `(?:` `)` to specify a non-capturing group, such the the caputure (`(` `)`) does not include whats in between dates (`.*`).

Answer (score 0):

you could use `stringr::str_extract_all()` instead, like this

```
str_extract_all(my_string, '\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+')
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_extract` would always return the first match. While there might be ways altering your regex to capture the `n`th occurrence of a pattern but a simple way would be to use `str_extract_all` and return the `n`th value.

```
library(stringr)
n <- 1
str_extract_all(my_string, '(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)')[[1]][n]
#[1] "19.01.03"
n <- 2
str_extract_all(my_string, '(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)')[[1]][n]
#[1] "20.01.22"
```

---

For the dataframe input we can extract all the date pattern and store it in a list and use `unnest_wider` to get them as separate columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = str_extract_all(string_col, '\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+')) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(date) %>%
  rename_with(~paste0('date', seq_along(.)), starts_with('..'))

# string_col                                           date1    date2   
#  <chr>                                                <chr>    <chr>   
#1 my string a-maxeka UU-AA-19.01.03-20.01.22-bamdanool 19.01.03 20.01.22
#2 my string a-maxeka UU-AA-20.01.08-20.04.01-jdasdasd  20.01.08 20.04.01
#3 asdad asda-adsad KK-ASD-20.05.05-jjj                 20.05.05 NA
```

Comment: As I work with the data.frame and I extract information from a column I need to extract the single occurance (`str_extract_all()[[1]][n]` is not vectorised and returns the first row elements only)

Comment: @jakes Can you update your post with the example of a dataframe that you have?

Comment: Updated the answer for a dataframe.  `rename_with` is in `dplyr` 1.0.0 so if you have an older version you can use `rename_at` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'd still prefer the regex-based solution though

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might need `str_extract_all`

```
str_extract_all(my_string, '(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)')
```

or `regmatches` if you prefer with base R

```
regmatches(my_string,gregexpr('(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)',my_string))
```

---

**Update**
With your data frame `df`

```
transform(df,
  date = do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      u <- str_extract_all(string_col, "(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)"),
      `length<-`,
      max(lengths(u))
    )
  )
)
```

we will get

```
                                            string_col   date.1   date.2
1 my string a-maxeka UU-AA-19.01.03-20.01.22-bamdanool 19.01.03 20.01.22
2  my string a-maxeka UU-AA-20.01.08-20.04.01-jdasdasd 20.01.08 20.04.01
3                 asdad asda-adsad KK-ASD-20.05.05-jjj 20.05.05     <NA>
```

Comment: As I work with the data.frame and I extract information from a column I need to extract the single occurance (`str_extract_all()[[1]][n]` is not vectorised and returns the first row elements only)

Comment: Thanks, I'd still prefer proper regex-based solution though

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example to showcase *{unglue}*.

Here you have 2 patterns (one date or two dates), the first is two dates separated by a dash and surrounded by anything, the second is a date surrounded by anything. We can write it this way :

```r
library(unglue)

unglue_unnest(
  df, string_col, 
  c("{}{date1=\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+}-{date2=\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+}{}", 
    "{}{date1=\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+}{}"), 
  remove = FALSE)
#>                                             string_col    date1    date2
#> 1 my string a-maxeka UU-AA-19.01.03-20.01.22-bamdanool 19.01.03 20.01.22
#> 2  my string a-maxeka UU-AA-20.01.08-20.04.01-jdasdasd 20.01.08 20.04.01
#> 3                 asdad asda-adsad KK-ASD-20.05.05-jjj 20.05.05     <NA>
```